# Prefixing numerically a string without change count status up to 5 matchs "In a text file with multiples matchs per line" using awk sub

Tags: awk, gsub, text-processing, prefix

Let's say I have the following file below, and I want to put a numeral prefix through the repetitive count in the range of `5` and prefixing the number repeated to `.dog`:

```
[.dog]
-house
.cat
.dog
foo.dogfish
[.dog]
-house
-house
.cat
foo.dogfish
.cat
.dog
[.dog]
-house

  [ -kitchen cat.dog 45_house-dog_.dogfish ]
 
    house_dogfish_cat

    'cat_.dog' -kitchen '
    :.;"house.cat()";
     food' today.cat


  [ -kitchen cat.dog ]
 
    house_dogfish_cat

    'cat_.dog' -kitchen '
    :.;"house.cat()";
     food' today.cat
 

  [ -kitchen cat.dog ]
 
    house_dogfish_cat

    'cat_.dog' -kitchen '
    :.;"house.cat()";
     food' today.cat
```

There are no cases where `.dog` should not be changed, then `.dog` should be changed to `number.dog` and even when `foo.dogfish` also be changed to `foo<number>.dogfish`, so than my outpout:

```
[1.dog]
-house
.cat
1.dog
foo1.dogfish
[1.dog]
-house
-house
.cat
foo1.dogfish
.cat
2.dog
[2.dog]
-house

  [ -kitchen cat2.dog 45_house-dog_2.dogfish ]
 
    house_dogfish_cat

    'cat_2.dog' -kitchen '
    :.;"house.cat()";
     food' today.cat


  [ -kitchen cat3.dog ]
 
    house_dogfish_cat

    'cat_3.dog' -kitchen '
    :.;"house.cat()";
     food' today.cat
 

  [ -kitchen cat3.dog ]
 
    house_dogfish_cat

    'cat_3.dog' -kitchen '
    :.;"house.cat()";
     food' today.cat
```

**EDIT UPDATE 1:** especially when desire `[ -kitchen cat.dog 45_house-dog_.dogfish ]` this changes to `[ -kitchen catnumber.dog 45_house-dog_number.dogfish ]`. I think a solution to avoid exections is to use something like `BEGIN{IGNORECASE =1 }/*not-match/`.

I have this code of User Cyrus:

```
 awk 'BEGIN{ count=1 } /\.dog/{ t=count; sub(/\..*/,"",t); sub(".dog", t "&"); count+=.2 }1' file
```

the only problem is that this code changes where say `[ -kitchen cat.dog 45_house-dog_.dogfish ]` to `[ -kitchen cat2.dog 45_house-dog_.dogfish ]` instead of the `[ -kitchen cat2.dog 45_house-dog_2.dogfish ]`. *We can summarize that the problem is that lines where `.dog` occurs once there is the correct prefixing, while in `.dog` lines occurs more than once only the first `.dog` occurs is prefixed numerically prefixed.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assumptions:

- for every occurrence of the string `.dog` prefix said string with an integer (`pfx`)
- said integer (`pfx`) starts @ `1` and increments `+1` after each `n=5` uses

One `awk` idea:

```
awk -v n=5 '
{ newline=""
  while ( x=index($0,".dog") ) {
        if (cnt++ % n == 0) pfx++                              # increment our prefix? cnt == number of times we have used pfx
        newline=newline substr($0,1,x-1) pfx substr($0,x,4)    # append pfx to this occurrence of ".dog"
        $0=substr($0,x+4)                                      # reset $0 to rest of line
  }
  print newline $0                                             # print newline plus anything left in $0
}
' dog.dat
```

**NOTE:** the `4` (in `x,4` and `x+4`) refers to the length of the search string `.dog`; if OP were to search for a different string then the `4's` would need to be updated accordingly (eg, if searching for `.dogs` then change the two `4's` to `5's`)

This generates:

```
[1.dog]
-house
.cat
1.dog
foo1.dogfish
[1.dog]
-house
-house
.cat
foo1.dogfish
.cat
2.dog
[2.dog]
-house

  [ -kitchen cat2.dog 45_house-dog_2.dogfish ]

    house_dogfish_cat

    'cat_2.dog' -kitchen '
    :.;"house.cat()";
     food' today.cat


  [ -kitchen cat3.dog ]

    house_dogfish_cat

    'cat_3.dog' -kitchen '
    :.;"house.cat()";
     food' today.cat


  [ -kitchen cat3.dog ]

    house_dogfish_cat

    'cat_3.dog' -kitchen '
    :.;"house.cat()";
     food' today.cat
```

---

fwiw, with `n=3` and a single line of input = `".dog .dog .dog .dog .dog .dog .dog .dog .dog .dog"` this generates:

```
1.dog 1.dog 1.dog 2.dog 2.dog 2.dog 3.dog 3.dog 3.dog 4.dog
```

Comment: `fwiw, with n=3 and a single line of input =` ... your comment on your answer was the heart of the problem, ie. Lines where there is more than one  `.dog` occurrence.

Comment: @7beggars_nnnnm yeah, figured as much; had the sample input (previous question) had the multiple instances per line I'm sure the answers you received would've addressed the issue ... hence the need to have sample inputs match (as closely as possible) the real world data

Comment: The user EdMorton warned me that there is no universal solution, a sample is required for each case. I had noticed this shortly before your answer but I did not remember commenting this in my post, but now I edited and made the comment about "multiple occurrences per line".

Comment: There is a form on the command-line  of your bash script?, I tried `awk -v n=5 '{ newline="" while ( x=index($0,".py") ) {if (cnt % n == 0) pfx++ newline=newline substr($0,1,x-1) pfx substr($0,x,4)$0=substr($0,x+4) cnt++} print newline $0}' dog.dat` to do it in a line but when I do acquire `syntax error` in `$0=substr($0,x+4) cnt++}`.

Comment: collapsing into a single line means having to add a copious amount of `;` to tell `awk` where one command ends and another starts, but not between conditionals and an associated single command; try ... `newline=""; while (...) { if(cnt%n==0) pfx++; newline=newline substr($0,1,x-1) pfx substr($0,x,4) ; $0=substr($0,x+4); cnt++}`

Comment: I have made an observation in user answer comment @_dan user about memory usage, your answer, for now offers better memory usage perfomance.

Comment: where says `pfx substr($0,x,4)` and `$0=substr($0,x+4);`  always must be `4` and `x + 4` respectively for any desired value of n (where in your sample n=5)? If so, you could add a more detailed explanation of the reason.

Comment: updated answer with explanation of the significance of the number `4` (the length of the search string `.dog`)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
awk -v RS='\\.dog' -v NR=4 '{ORS = int(NR/5)".dog"; print}'
```

Which works, apart from an extra, trailing `N.dog` (at the very end of the file).

So you could fix that trailing `N.dog` with this version (or a better way? (**edit:** added better way at the end)):

```
awk -v RS='\\.dog' \
'{
    lines[NR]=$0 int((NR+4)/5)".dog"
}

END {
        ORS = ""

        for(i=0; i<NR; i++) {
            print lines[i]
        }

        print $0
}'
```

**Explanation:** using the target string (`.dog`) as the record separator, count the records and print count/5 between each record and record separator.

**Note: POSIX 2018:**

> If RS contains more than one character, the results are unspecified.

However, various `awk`s do implement regex for `RS`. It’s documented in `mawk` and `gawk`. Both examples above were tested in `mawk`, `gawk`, and `busybox awk`.

**edit, better solution:**
As per comments, here is a full solution that won’t copy the input file to memory, and won’t print an extra `N.dog`:

```
awk -v RS='\\.dog' -v NR=4 \
'(NR != 5) {print line}
{ORS = int(NR/5)".dog"; line=$0}
END {ORS = ""; print}'
```

Or more readable (identical):

```
awk -v RS='\\.dog' -v NR=4 \
'{
    if (NR != 5) {
        print line
    }

    ORS = int(NR/5)".dog"
    line=$0
}

END {
    ORS = ""
    print
}'
```

Comment: Actually the first command line creates an extra `.dog`, 14 goes for 15 occurrences. But as you opened yourself in the second complementary code, this extra `.dog` is corrected and your response works well!

Comment: I believe your answer, although it actually works, requires more memory than the previous markp-fuso user answer. Make the following test: Considering that the text to be processed from my question was `1.txt`, so replicate this text one million times `perl -ne 'if (1..41) {push @data,$_};END{print @data for 1..1000000};' 1.txt > new_text.txt` ,  try to process this `new_text.txt` instead of my original text of 40 lines of my question.

Comment: @7beggars_nnnnm You can pipe the first version in to `sed '$d'`. I will update the answer.

Comment: @dan I should note that whilst piping the first version  to `sed '$d'` would work, if the last line of input data didn’t have a trailing new line, it would get deleted. I updated the answer with a better solution, that just doesn’t print the last `ORS` at all.

Comment: Ok @dan i Will check

Comment: @7beggars_nnnnm If you do have that much data, you might actually be better off using the first version, which is the most efficient, and piping to either `sed '$d'`, or `sed -E '${s/[0-9]+\.dog$//}'` to remove the last `N.dog`. On my laptop, this was 20% faster than my final `awk` solution.